# C++ - 2D array as an method argument

Tags: c++

I've got class similar to this:

```
class Krzyzowka
{
    protected:
    char model[40][40];
    int x, y;

    public:
        Krzyzowka() { }

            Krzyzowka(char model[][40], int x, int y)
            {
                this->model=model;
            }
};
```

Now, I declare in main():

```
char array[10][10];
```

and want to pass it to the:

```
Krzyzowka(char model[][40], int x, int y)
```

I'm doing it this way:

```
Krzyzowka obj(array, 10, 10);
```

But then I want to set the model 2D array with the passed array:

```
this->model=model;
```

But compiler returns two errors:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Krzyzowka::Krzyzowka(char [10][10], int, int)’

error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘char (*)[40]’ to ‘char [40][40]’
```

How can I do this correctly? Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Say what? Correctly pass a [10][10] array as a [40][40] array?

Comment: `Krzyzowka` is a crossword puzzle, so why not use a `std::vector<std::string>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no operation available that automatically assigns an array to another array.

Possible workarounds that come to mind:

---

Manually copy-assign the data to your internal array using a loop (make sure to keep track of the effective `nrows` and `ncols`). For circumventing the compiler complaints you could use a template (assuming the size is known at compile time):

```
    template<int NROWS, int NCOLS>
    Krzyzowka(char (&model)[NROWS][NCOLS])
    {
        nrows = NROWS > nrows ? nrows : NROWS;
        ncols = NCOLS > ncols ? ncols : NCOLS;
        for (int row = 0; row < nrows; row++)
          for (int col = 0; col < ncols; col++) 
            this->model[row][col] = model[row][col];
    }
```

Now you can create the object like:

```
char array[][2] = {{'a', 'b'}, {'c', 'd'}};
Krzyzowka k(array);
```

---

If the dimensions of the array are only known at run time (e.g. based on user input, and `char** array` dynamically allocated by nested `new[]`), you may need to adopt the approach [given here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10547506/1025391) or switch to the following.

---

Even better would probably be to use some standard array type, like `std::vector` (which you can swap or assign). Then you have no problem with the compiler type incompatility complaints either.

```
std::vector<std::vector<char> > array(nrows, std::vector<char>(ncols));
std::vector<std::vector<char> > model;
model = array; // or model.swap(array); if you don't need the copy
```

Comment: I really would like to use char array for a model. If I use:

    char array[nrows][ncols];
    char **model;
    model = array;

what should be my constructor prototype?

Answer (score 2):

Parameter `char model[][40]` could be used only for array like `parameter[x][40]`.

If you really want to pass any row array to the method, you could use pointer:

```
class Krzyzowka
{
    protected:
        char **pp_model;
        int x, y;

    public:
        Krzyzowka() { }

        Krzyzowka(char **pp_model, int x, int y)
        {
            this->pp_model = pp_model;

            // do not miss follow two line
            this->x = x;
            this->y = y;
        }
};
```

Then, you could pass `char **` parameter to instantiate the object instead of using `char array[x][y]`.

And Now that you use `c++`. You'd better not use row array. that's [evil](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/containers.html). You could use stl vector instead.

May that be helpful for you :)